# Programmatic (Apex code) approach advantages

Tags: apex

Generally, when is it most suitable to use apex instead of a declarative approach? Also please share a link or resource if possible?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce's best practice is "clicks, not code." That means you should prefer declarative methods whenever possible. It's hard to summarize definitively, but generally speaking, you should at least research if you can avoid Apex. Process Builder, Flows, and Validation Rules cover many typical use cases. Flows can also create simple wizard-like user interfaces (UIs) instead of Visualforce, Aura Components, and Lightning Web Components (LWC). And new technologies, like Aura and LWC can make some kinds of data retrieval and DML operations without any Apex. Where to draw the line usually comes as a matter of experience, and no simple guide on the Internet will give you every single possible circumstance and solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's two design guides from the Salesforce Architects site that cover the following:

1. [Building Forms](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/build-forms/)
2. [Record-Triggered Automation](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/trigger-automation/)

It's important to stress that this is all dependent on your team/situation, but declarative tools are generally easy for anyone to understand or maintain.

> In a case where multiple tools are available for a use case, **we
> recommend choosing the tool that will allow you to implement and
> maintain the use case with the lowest cost**.
>
> This will be highly dependent on the makeup of your team.

From the UI point of view, the following points are stressed:

1. For basic create/edit forms on a Lightning record page on desktop,
   use Dynamic Forms.
2. Use Flow to build multi-screen forms. If you need to also meet
   precise UX requirements, layer in LWCs.
3. If you need test automation, start with LWC. You can write unit
   tests for any LWC, regardless of where you plan to embed it.

From the automation point of view

1. If you have high performance batch processing needs or expect highly
   sophisticated implementation logic, use Apex.
2. Recommend implementing asynchronous processing inside a [Queueable Apex class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm)
3. The cost of which you choose is dependent on your team. Generally, in an environment where there are mixed skill sets or admin-heavy skill sets, Flow triggers provide a very compelling option that is more performant and easier to debug, maintain, and extend than any no-code offering of the past.
4. The [Choose the Right Automation Tool](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/process_whichtool) trailhead also has this blurb about when to use Apex

> Use Apex when you need more functionality than is available in Flow
> Builder. Build the more complex functionality as invocable Apex
> methods. Then call the resulting Apex as an Apex action in the process
> or as an Apex action element in the flow.

There's much more information in those two design guides above to assist in making your design decisions, but it's generally considered that declarative tools will be the quickest to implement and lowest cost to maintain. Your final deign might bridge across the two as a combination (flow + apex) can retain the benefits of declarative tools as well as handle aspects that may require complex logic.

**TL;DR** The advantage of what you choose depends on your team's skills and what allows you the lowest cost to maintain. Generally, that will be declarative tools. If none of the existing declarative tools meet the need (ex. processing speed, functionality, etc) completely, consider apex or some combination of declarative + apex.